# REST Call to Firebase Database with Token returns Error "Missing claim 'kid' in auth header."

Tags: java, rest, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, okhttp

I'm trying to make a REST call to my Firebase Database. I have had success using my database secret, but I am trying to use a token instead. When I make my rest call with the token I am receiving the error:

```
"error" : "Missing claim 'kid' in auth header."
```

I am making a call from my server because for other reasons I cannot use the server SDK so I must use REST. I am open to other solutions but essentially I want to be able to use the database rules. It is my impression that if you use the SECRET it overwrites the defined rules.

```
String uid = "123";
Map<String, Object> auth = new HashMap<String, Object>();
auth.put("uid", uid);

FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
        .setServiceAccount(new FileInputStream(serviceAccountJson))
        .setDatabaseUrl(myFirebaseAddress)
        .setDatabaseAuthVariableOverride(auth)
        .build();
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);

String customToken = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().createCustomToken(uid);

Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url("myFirebaseAddress"+"/users.json?auth="+customToken)
        .build();

Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

String responseString = response.body().string();
System.out.println(responseString);
```

Comment: Did you got this working.. facing the same problem